# Emacs editor "locks" out terminal when being used

Tags: macos, emacs, terminal

The issue I am having is when I open a file via emacs it will open another window in the emacs text editor, but lock out the terminal. What I mean by lock out is that the terminal seems to be linked to the window of emacs that had opened up. When I first downloaded the software I did not have this issue and was able to open multiple emacs windows at once but now I have to close out of the current emacs window to open another. Any suggestions on fixing this?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to have the file pop up in a window when you open it, rather than fill the whole terminal.

If that's the case, you should

1. install a graphical version of Emacs from http://emacsformacosx.com/
2. put `alias emacs=/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs` in you `~/.bashrc`
3. open files with `emacs file.txt &`. The file will open in a separate window and you can keep using your terminal

Comment: Just to piggyback, the real trick here is step 3. That "&" at the end will send the emacs process to the background, allowing you to interact with the terminal through the command prompt (and not killing emacs when you close that terminal).